# how to fix: attempt to index global "f" (a nil value), LUA I/O text editing

Tags: lua

As title says that error appears when executing the following code.

//open the file

```
local out = io.open('path', 'r')
```

//Fetch all lines and add them to a table

```
local lines = {}
for line in f:lines() do  
    table.insert(lines, line)
end
```

//close

```
  out:close()
```

//insert line

```
 table.insert(lines, 8, "test this bullshit\n")
```

//temporary file

```
local out = io.open('pathnew', 'w')
for _, line in ipairs(lines) do
    out:write(line)
end
```

//close temporary

```
   out:close()
```

//delete old file (from the first io.open)

```
os.remove('pathold')
```

//rename temporary file to the old one (from the first io.open)

```
os.rename('pathnew', 'pathold')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening a file you call `out` but then try to read lines from a file you call `f`. `f` doesn’t exist.

Comment: I did as you say, now it does work, however instead of it going to the 8th line it merges with everything else inside the txt file.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean when you say it ‘merges with everything else’. Also, you need to be careful: When you call `os.remove(‘pathold’)`, thats the first time you ever use `pathold`. I’d suggest trying to learn to debug your errors. Trace through your code carefully, line by line.

Comment: I meant that the line doesnt get written where I want it to be written (in this case 8th line in the txt file), its a simple code only meant for txt (for now, so I'm not worried) oh and my error, pathold is the path for the f.

Comment: Where is it getting written?

Comment: It deletes every other line and then combines what I input + old txt that was there, as in makes it one line.

Comment: Again, you’ll need to debug what is happening. Use `print` to display the lines of the table during the loops. Double check your file paths. Don’t name the first file you open `old`, and then use that name again for the file you write to. Keep things separate and be clear as to what each command is doing.

Comment: @Normanx, does your input file have `\r\n` line endings? Also, I believe `write()` does not append a newline for you: you have to do that yourself.